# Stopping counter with rails-timeago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, timeago

I am timing a task from the date with the gem rails-timeago. The count appears in the view and I use the following code for this:

```
<% = Timeago_tag task.data,: nojs => true,: limit => 10.days.ago%>
```

I want to develop a button that when clicking the time count stops.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose to use this gem?
Which time tracking you want to make, what is the idea?

Comment: I have a small system where the user can register tasks according to title, description and date and time of accomplishment.

The gem is being used to count the time the user is taking to perform a task.

I would like a "Complete Task" button that would change the state to "completed task" and stop the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem is not what you need and have another purpose. It's just a helper, that using your timestamps (`created_at`/`updated_at`) and draw up it's appearance.

You can add new field (timestamp) into your database `completed_at` and save there the time of task that was completed. You can also add `started_at` and use it as timestamp for time when task was started or simply use `created_at`. You still can use `time_ago` gem to count elapsed time or output it in a pretty appearance.

Comment: Thank you. I created the complete_at field, how do I save the time information when the user clicks the "Completed Task?

Comment: @DenisPolicarpo There are a few approaches. You can add `state_machine` gem, you can use model's callbacks, or if you don't want to dig deep and make fast but dirty stuff, just add line at controller `task.completed_at = Time.zone.now` into method where you saving your task.